# Can't return two differnt text values with forumula

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

I'm using this code:

```
=IF(Age>=5,"1W","0", =IF(Age>=10,"2W","0"))
```

I cant get it to return the values of 1W or 2W in the field. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create a calculate column using formula, use this formula:

```
=IF([Age]>=10,"2W",IF([Age]>=5,"1W","0"))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display* names of your columns in the formula.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))